# GWT won't load java simple code (display a button)

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to display a simple button.
Here's the code (Project.java):

```
package com.attempt.project.client;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;

public class Project implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
      final Button button = new Button("Click me");
      RootPanel.get("project").add(button);
  }
}
```

And here's Project.hml:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<!-- ... -->
<!-- code given by GWT by default -->
<!-- ... -->
<h1>Project</h1>

 <table align=center>
  <tr>
    <td id="project"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h1> Done </h1>    
  </body>
</html>
```

What I get in return in my browser is just:

```
Project

Done
```

I already tried using the div tag instead of td, but nothing changes.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the sample produced by Google Eclipse Plugin?

Comment: Do you have a <entry-point class='pathToYourEntrypoint'/>-tag in your module descriptor?

Comment: Please check the `<script type="text/javascript" src="B2Boost/B2Boost.nocache.js"></script>` is in the `<head>` section of your html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your HTML file has a link to the `module.nocache.js` file for the module that contains `Project.java`. Also make sure the path to that `js` file is correct. For example:

```html
<script src="module_name/module_name.nocache.js"></script>
```

Comment: also, make `align=center` into  `align="center"`

Comment: The following line was already included in Project.html:
    `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="project/project.nocache.js"></script>`
and the location is correct, since Project.html is in `/war`, and `project.nocache.js`is in `/war/project/project.nocache.js`.

Comment: @elmazzun Ok, that seems correct. You'll know for sure if you inspect the page and it doesn't show a 404 error in "network" tab. Next, if your `onModuleLoad()` method only has those two lines and nothing else that may cause an error, add a third line that will `Window.alert("Module loaded");` to make sure that it does indeed load. Third, make sure your `PROJECT.gwt.xml` file has a `<entry-point class="com.attempt.project.client.Project"/>` entry. IF none of that works, try to make a sample project with the GWT plugin and see if the issue is reproducible.